# The underlying type theory of HOL/Isabelle

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, proof-assistants

Is there a good source on the type theory of HOL/Isabelle/other HOL-based LCF-style theorem provers?

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/Isabelle2018/doc/implementation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Isabelle's implementation manual is a good place to look at this. It may certainly contain links to the explanation but you can find instead a pedagogical introduction in section 2 of [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00399).